# MongoDB stitch-cli import failed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-stitch

As described in the following page,

https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/import-export/create-stitch-app/

I made a file named `stitch.json` which contains an empty JSON. i.e.
{}

But when I run `stitch-cli import`, I got error following

> this app does not exist yet: would you like to create a new app? [y/n]: y
>
> App name: Experimental
>
> failed to find Project ID: an unexpected server error has occurred

I'm working on

**MacOS 10.13.5**

**stitch-cli 1.0.1**

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: App name should be Project ID, According to documentation "You can find your Atlas Project ID listed on the Settings page of the Atlas UI."
But still i get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$ stitch-cli import --project-id=XXX
```

You can find your Atlas Project ID listed on the Settings page of the Atlas UI